# Ruby Tempfile#tap: What class defines this method and what is it for?

Tags: ruby, temporary-files, httparty

I've found this piece of code in a pull request someone made to one of my gems:

```
source = HTTParty.get(PoliticosBR::DEPUTADOS_URL)
tempfile = Tempfile.new('deputados.xls').tap do |f|
  f.write(source.to_s.force_encoding('UTF-8'))
end
```

The idea is getting a remote Excel file with HTTParty and then write it to a Tempfile for reading its data. Nothing fancy and it is working fine.

But I'm not very used to Ruby Tempfile and then I decided to read [its documentation](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/ruby/ruby_2_2_0_stdlib/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) in order to learn more about it. But I haven't found a `#tap` method there.

Then I tried the [File documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html) and then again I could find nothing about `#tap`.

**Where is this method defined?**

**What is it for?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#tap` is defined on `Object`

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-tap

It was introduced in Ruby 1.9. It yields self to the block and then returns self. I think an illustrative example is when it's used to return an object from a method.

You could do this.

```
def foo
  a = []
  a.push(3)
  a
end

def foo
  [].tap do |a|
    a.push(3)
  end
end
```

In the first example the array a is returned explicitly and in the second tap is being used to yield the block to self and then return self.

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't understand how this apply to that specific piece of code in my question.

Comment: I got it! It is just "sending" the Tempfile created to the block, in order to use it inside.